# postgres string type compatibility: varchar and character

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

On my postgresql database, i've declared all String field as

```
character(n)
```

Now i have some function that takes string argument as

```
varchar(n)
```

are this two datatype compatible or should i change type in function or in table declarement?

Comment: Don't use `char` or `character`, they're horrible legacy data types with surprising and confusing behaviours. Use `varchar` or `text`.

Comment: i was using character instead varchar because of some mysql scripting habit :) now i've modify all my db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character types `character(n)` and `varchar(n)` are compatible and internally are the same type (but have different representation, when queried).

Details in [`this article`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html)